# Converting string to datetime split into date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime-format

I am trying to convert string '2022-12-28T22:28:43.260781049Z' to datetime format.

I have such query:

```
SELECT  date(str_to_date('2022-12-28T22:28:43.260781049Z','%Y-%m-%d')) as date,
        hour(str_to_date('2022-12-28T22:28:43.260781049Z',"%H:%M:%S")) as hour
FROM transaction
```

And such output:

| date | time |
| --- | --- |
| '2022-12-28' | NULL |

How to get time as well?

Comment: `%M = Month name in full (January to December)` **not minutes** so try `%i  Minutes (00 to 59)` Its always useful when things go wrong, but only as a last resort, to [Reference the user manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: You can use TIME('2022-12-28T22:28:43.260781049Z') to get time in this format 00:20:22

Comment: That would not correspond to the correct time associated to that timestamp. That would be the result of parsing 2022 year to 00:20:22. I guess the OP wants "22:28:43" as parsed time. @Dejan

Comment: @lemon thanks for bringing that to my attention, my bad then

Comment: As @lemon pointed out we should cast it to DATETIME first.
TIME(CAST('2022-12-28T22:28:43.260781049Z' as DATETIME)) will return time in this format 22:28:43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use a [`CAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) on your string value to `TIMESTAMP`, then extract the date and the time with the hononimous [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) and [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) MySQL functions.

```
SELECT DATE(CAST(timestamp_ AS DATETIME)) AS date_,
       TIME(CAST(timestamp_ AS DATETIME)) AS time_
FROM transactions;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ncakEyfoxrPYJXCYk9Vczo/0).

Answer (score 0):

Use timestamp instead of str_to_date:

```
SELECT hour(timestamp('2022-12-28T22:28:43.260781049Z')) as hour
```